# Merge rows from cross referenced tables 

Tags: sql-server, merge, rows, junction-table

I'd like to create a SQL Server `select` statement where the cross referenced data are in one column from different rows. I'd like to use `stuff` (if possible) and no `;with` command.

**Contract** table

```
ID  Subject
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

**Company** table

```
ID  Name
1   a_ltd
2   b_ltd
3   c_ltd
4   d_ltd
5   e_ltd
```

**ContractContractorCrossRef** table (junction table)

```
ID  ContractID_ CompanyID_
1   1               1
2   1               2
3   2               3
4   3               1
5   3               4
6   3               5
```

I'd like this result:

```
Contract.ID company.Name
1           a_ltd, b_ltd
2           c_ltd
3           a_ltd, d_ltd, e_ltd
```

**Populate data:**

```
create table #Contract (ID INT, Subject VARCHAR(1))
INSERT  #Contract
SELECT  1, 'a' UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'c'

create table #Company (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(5))
INSERT  #Company
SELECT  1, 'a_ltd' UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'b_ltd' UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'c_ltd' UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'd_ltd' UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'e_ltd'

create table #ccRef (ID INT, ContractID_ INT, CompanyID_ INT)
INSERT  #ccRef
SELECT  1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 3, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 3, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 3, 5
```

**Select:**

```
select #Contract.ID, #Company.Name from #Contract
inner join #ccRef on #Contract.ID = #ccRef.ContractID_ inner join #Company
on #ccRef.CompanyID_ = #Company.ID
```

**Select result: (not wanted)**

```
ID  Name
1   a_ltd
1   b_ltd
2   c_ltd
3   a_ltd
3   d_ltd
3   e_ltd
```

**Requested result:**

```
Contract.ID company.Name
1           a_ltd, b_ltd
2           c_ltd
3           a_ltd, d_ltd, e_ltd
```

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why do your requirements include `stuff` and no CTE?

Comment: I read a lot about XML Path and STUFF to make this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have not tested the code as i do not have ddl for these tables.But it should work..

```
       SELECT ct.id ,
 left(companyname.value('.','varchar(max)'), len(companyname.value('.','varchar(max)'))-1) as companyname 
from 
    contract ct 
    cross apply 
    ( 
    select cm.name + ',' [text()]
    from 
    contractcompanycrossref cc 

    inner join company cm
    on cc.companyid = cm.ID
      where ct.id = cc.contractid 
    for xml path (''),type
    ) cmnames(companyname)
```

Comment: Something is wrong with syntax, but I have a solution already. Thank you. "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'."

Comment: Sorry try now I have tested on the link provided by you..sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3004/18

Comment: It is working. Thank you. Do you have any idea, why is the result &amp; instead of & (ampersand) character when & character is in the company name. Is it a collation?
(Database: 'a&ltd' - Result: 'a&amp;ltd'

Comment: This is related to xml but in the above link it is not showing the amp;

Comment: It is working fine on the link above, but on sql server not. I have found an article about this:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT x.id
  , left(CompanyName, len(CompanyName)-1) as CompanyName
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ct.id
    , (SELECT CAST(co.Name + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
           FROM contractcompanycrossref cc
           LEFT JOIN company co
            on cc.companyid = co.id
           WHERE (cc.contractid = ct.id) 
           FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) AS CompanyName
  from contract ct
  left join contractcompanycrossref cc
    on ct.id = cc.contractid
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3004/14)

Comment: This is my result:<br/>
id CompanyName <br/>
1 a_ltd <br/>
2 b_ltd <br/>
3 c_ltd <br/>

Comment: Did you see my SQL Fiddle?  It is producing the results you asked for.